# file of strings into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io

I have a file of strings seperated by space and I want to get those strings into an array of defined type but I get an error saying that fscanf doesn't take char**, does anyone know how to do this please?

```
typedef struct{
      char *string;
      int name;
      } DBZ;

DBZ Table[100];

fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
    exit(1);
}
else {
    int i=0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s", &Table[i].string);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> &Table[i].string

You're taking an address of a pointer, which is a pointer-of-a-pointer, which is a char**

Also,

fscanf provides no functionality to **allocate** the memory you need. You'll have to malloc a block large enough to hold whats in your file. Then you'll want to use something safer than fscanf, preferable the [most secure thing available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx)* to make sure you don't overwrite the buffer.

```
else {
    int i=0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        Table[i].string = malloc(100);
        fscanf_s(fp,"%s", Table[i].string, 100);
        i++;
    }
}
```

* These are Microsoft extensions, your platform may have something different.

Comment: The safer_than_fscanf link may not be applicable to his platform though.

Comment: In the first line, you mean `char **`.

Comment: Also, to make sure you don't read more than a certain number of characters, you could give `"%100s"` for example as format string. Unfortunately, unlike `printf`, you can't give `"%*s"` and give that number as an integer.

Comment: And if you're using extensions, the GNU C Library has an allocation flag to the %s conversion. `%as` I believe. That will return an allocated string pointer. Not recommended for portable code though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&`, Table[i].string is already a pointer.

string also needs to contain memory. You could change the definition of your struct to:

```
typedef struct{
      char string[90];
      int name;
} DBZ;
```

That assumes that your data will fit in 90 bytes. Depending on what your data is, it could also be a very inefficient way of storing it. `malloc()`, as others have pointed out, could help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for `char *string` in your struct. And your %s takes **char*** not char**